# Python web browser for Android

Tags: python, android, web

I want to create a web browser for android, if possible with python. I never created an android app in python also not really sure how to do something like this.

Are there any good tipps for it?
Should I use another langue for it?
Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are made up of many components, such as rendering engines, JavaScript engines, and UI, each of which can be written in different languages.

```
Firefox

Rendering engine: Gecko, C++, and in recent versions Rust language used too
JavaScript engine: SpiderMonkey, C
UI: Mostly XUL (a custom XML dialect), CSS, and JavaScript, with some C++.



Chrome

Rendering engine: WebCore, C++
JavaScript engine: V8, C++
UI: Mostly C++, though the mac port uses Objective-C, and some features in all platforms use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.



Safari

Rendering engine: WebCore, C++ (shared with Chrome)
JavaScript engine: JavaScriptCore, C++
UI: Unknown, but likely Objective-C with some HTML
```